# Href only works with http

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio

I want to redirect to a different page when clicking on my H2.
The thing is it only works if I have http on the code.

```
<h2 id="btn_share">Share...</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("btn_share").onclick = function () {
            location.href = "http://www.google.html";
        };
    </script>
```

I have the google link as an example. What I really want is to redirect to a local page, therefore I cannot use the http://. But it does not work. But also, if I just write "www.google.com" it does not work. It only works with http:// 
Why? And how to fix it?

(I am using Microsoft Visual Studio)

Comment: just use a relative path.

Comment: You could put the `<h2>` within a `<a>` if you're working with html5 (it would also work with older versions of html actually), so no JS needed.

Comment: //www.google.com will use the same protocol as the current page

Comment: Why can't you use `http://` for a local page? Do you mean you are trying to use a relative path?

Comment: An HREF must contain a legal URL as defined in the HTML specification (this includes relative URLs too).  The browser, on the other hand, lets you type lots of things into the browser bar that are NOT legal URLs per that specification and are not appropriate inside your HTML.  Thus, you can type `www.google.com` in the browser URL bar, but you cannot put it in an HREF.  For that, you must add a protocol or the `//` which indicates to use the same protocol as the host page on the front of the URL to make it legal.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a local path.
Here's how it works:
`http://www.google.com` or `//www.google.com` will give you Google's website, because the `//` tells the browser to use the protocol of whatever current page is (`http://`, for example). Obviously, you can specify it yourself.

If you prefix the link with a single `/`, it will start from the root of the current domain. For example, from `http://www.example.com/example/example2.html` with a link to `/about` would bring the user to `http://www.example.com/about`

Excluding the `/` or using a `./` will search the local directory. For example, from `http://www.example.com/example/example2.html` with a link to `about` would bring the user to `http://www.example.com/example/about`

Hope this helps.